# Android PlusClient implementation & getting a token

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus

so i implemented google plus login to my app... my implementation pretty closely follows the example given [here](https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/5170508). The biggest difference between mine and his is that i have a larger set of scopes that i require. when building my plusclient i specify the following scopes:

```
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
```

later down the line in my onConnected method i attempt to get an accesstoken from my session in order to pass to our server where we do the real meat & potatos work.

```
    GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(SplashActivity.this, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email")
```

this does yield an accesstoken. YIPPEE! right? nope. when we try and use this token it seems that it is not associated with our app. when running the token through googles tokeninfo endpoint, we get something along the lines of

```
{
 "issued_to": "608941808256-43vtfndets79kf5hac8ieujto8837660.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "608941808256-43vtfndets79kf5hac8ieujto8837660.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "user_id": "107245641469745809180",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "expires_in": 3577,
 "email": "redacted@email.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "access_type": "online"
}
```

that issued_to value does not match up with any of our client id's. according to the last part of [this blog post](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/03/common-problems-with-google-sign-in-on.html) google is unable to match this token request up with our project. however, in our API console i do indeed have the SHA fingerprint in there for android and it is indeed separated with the package name by a semicolon. no spelling mistakes. i've waited hours to see if it was a propagation issue. i also added the SHA fingerprint and whatnot to create a clientid for our debug keystore. we have the same issue whether we export a signed apk out of eclipse or if we run it directly.

this is driving me insane. i don't know where to turn with this.

as an example, when making a call to

googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?access_token=TOKEN_HERE&maxResults=100&pageToken=&alt=json&orderBy=best

i get

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

because google for whatever reason did not associate that token with my project.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I can't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so far, this is coming across as a bug in the google api.

if i take out the "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds" scope then everything works and the token is successfully associated with our project. if "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds" is included as a requested scope, everything breaks on the api side despite the fact that it prompts the user properly for that specific permission. although we still get a token when requesting this scope, the token is not associated with our project.

Comment: Just for everyone else, you need a trailing slash on that URL: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ - it will fail to match the scope without it, and give an error.

Comment: i really appreciate your help. wow. all i can say is wow. a missing slash. haha. i maintain my opinion that it is a bug in the api however. when requesting this scope without the trailing slash it does resolve and notify the user in that permissions page that we are requesting this permission, but things break in the linkage of the token to our app... either way, thank you thank you thank you :-)

Comment: also, interestingly enough... when you run the token you get after using or not using the slash through that tokeninfo endpoint it actually shows the scope with and without the slash in the list of associated scopes. perhaps there are two m8/feeds scopes that are resolving?

Answer (score 1):

```
 String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity(), plusClient.getAccountName(),    
 "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE + " " + MY_SCOPE);
```

My code works. Maybe you have unnecessary lable after "oauth2:"

Comment: yea the code works for me too... i get an accesstoken.... its just that the access token is not associated with our project. i can make a call to "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" but any other calls with that token, as i mentioned above, yield a 403

Comment: i'm using "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" as my scopes

Comment: thats the first one i listed